# Want to store Object in MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, object, types

I have a variable in java which return type is Object(java.lang.Object). I want to store this variable value in MySQL database without casting in any other primitive data type. Is there any data type available in MySQL related to Object?

Comment: Note that it's generally not a good idea to store a serialized object in a database (other than maybe temporarily) because a change to the class of the object could make the serialized object stored in the database incompatible with it.

Comment: That sure would make things easy. Look into ORM or OODBMS. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `BLOB` to store the raw data, but otherwise no, MySQL does not have a datatype specifically for a java object.

As a side note: You probably shouldn't be storing a raw object into the database, that kind of prevents you from doing any sort of queries on it.

Answer (score 3):

You must serialize the Object anyway, so you could serialize to XML or JSON aswell. A human readable storage form is what I would prefer.
Have a look at [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) for example. A great, threadsafe tool for marshalling/unmarshalling.

I assume of course, that your Object is a Bean/POJO.

Answer (score 2):

BLOB could do it.  Serialize the object into a byte array and INSERT that as a BLOB.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by `Object(java.lang.Object)`. but I think if you tried JSON datatype in MySQL it'll work fine.

```sql
create table person (name JSON );
INSERT INTO person VALUES ('{"pid": 101, "name": "name1"}');
INSERT INTO person VALUES ('{"pid": 102, "name": "name2"}');
```

or

```sql
INSERT INTO person VALUES (JSON_OBJECT("pid",103,"name", "name3"));
```